# Issue creating concordion-extensions-demo with Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml, concordion

I am trying to create the concordion-extensions-demo (located at http://concordion.org/Download.html) project with Maven.

When I run the command mvn test I receive errors ...

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

In the POM there are variables for ..

concordion.version, concordion-extensions.version and slf4j.version.

Do I need to update these tags with actual version numbers?

As is probably obvious I am not an experienced software devoloper or have much experience with Maven. Does anyone have an idea as to what the problem could be and how I could resolve this?

Thanks.

Tam.

Comment: Sorry. I found solution for this problem on here. I added below dependency to POM...<dependency>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. Concordion also has a transitive dependency on an older version of `xml-apis`. I'm not sure why Maven was unable to resolve the conflict. Rather than add an explicit dependency to `xml-apis`, I've added an exclusion for the `xml-apis` dependency.to the pom, and created a new release of the [download](http://concordion-extensions.googlecode.com/files/concordion-extensions-demo-1.1.0.4.zip)